# How to convert GML Surface to SHP Using OGR?

Tags: ogr, ogr2ogr, gml

I have a very large `.gml` file with multiple layers in it.  I would like to export one of these layers to `.shp`.  It is a polygon layer (of lakes).  However, I am getting the error:

> ERROR 1: Unrecognised geometry type `<Surface>`.

The ogr command I was using: 
`ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" output.shp input.gml layername`

Any thoughts?  Is it possible the polygon layer is somehow incorrectly defined as a surface in the GML?  Any way I can force it to be a polygon?  Or is it something else entirely?  I don't often work with `.gml`, so may be missing something obvious...

EDIT 20101202:
Here is a snip of (what appears to be) the relevant info from an example feature in the example file linked below:

```
<gml:featureMember>
    <gml:surfaceProperty>
        <gml:Surface srsName="EPSG:4140" srsDimension="2">
            <gml:patches>
                <gml:PolygonPatch>
                    <gml:exterior>
                        <gml:LinearRing>
                           <gml:posList>
                               52.2023177 -77.596532 52.2024007 -77.5963559 52.2028141 -77.5962899 52.2028362 -77.5964181 52.2026119 -77.5967049 52.2024106 -77.5967968 52.2023273 -77.5966966 52.2023177 -77.596532
                           </gml:posList>
                        </gml:LinearRing>
                    </gml:exterior>
             </gml:PolygonPatch>
        </gml:patches>
    </gml:Surface>
</gml:surfaceProperty>
```

So, the file is identifying it as a 'surface' as well as a 'PolygonPatch'?  Perhaps the question should be:  what is a 'surface' in a .gml file?

Comment: What is the output of "ogrinfo input.gml -ro -al"?

Comment: ogrinfo gives the same "ERROR 1: Unrecognised geometry type <Surface>."

Comment: Are you using the latest version of GDAL/OGR? http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_gml.html

Comment: I am using 1.7.0b2

Comment: Can you post a sample of the GML or a link to the file?

Comment: If you really think that OGR is incorrectly reading the GML, I would post the issue to the FWTools list.  Frank usually fixes things pretty quickly.

Comment: An example file (not the massive one I was originally working on, but should be similar) is here: http://ftp2.cits.nrcan.gc.ca/pub/canvec/50k_gml/033/c/canvec_033c04_gml.zip - the data should contain Canadian topo data, so it should all be points/lines/polygons.  An ogrinfo -al -ro -so on this file gives a number of layers as 'Unrecognized geometry type (Surface)'.  For example, Layer HD_1490009_2, which according to the metadata, should be 'islands'  (all layers with _2 at the end are 'areas').

Comment: see http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/gml for details of the differences between GML2 and GML3.

Comment: @iant - wow. Lots of documentation there.  Can anyone with some existing knowledge summarize for me?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use GDAL 1.8.0 or above to be able to read this kind of GML3 geometry.

Comment: if somebody knows, that's you Even :)

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you have GML3 but ogr2ogr is expecting it to be GML2. According to the docs (http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_gml.html) only GML 2 or GML 3 Simple Feature is supported, since GML3 SF doesn't support surfaces either I'd say you are out of luck.

I'm also not entirely sure if a shapefile can support surfaces either so I suspect that you are going to run into problems with any solution trying to go this way.

Comment: The issue is that the feature should be a polygon, according to all of the documentation I can find.  It appears that OGR is identifying it incorrectly as a surface when it shouldn't.

Comment: It seems more likely that the documentation of your data is wrong than OGR is misreading "polygon" as "surface" but a quick grep of the data file should solve the issue.

Comment: I have pasted a snippit into the original question.