# Convert GML to GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, visualisation, gml, d3

I have downloaded a GML file from Statistics Canada and would like to convert it into GeoJSON to use parts of it in a D3 visualization on the web. However, I did not find a converter that would do that for me (I tried http://converter.mygeodata.eu/ , but the GeoJSON it returned did not contain any actual geometry).

What is the best approach to convert GML into GeoJSON?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You Can use [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html). Simplest to install it would be to download [fwTools](http://fwtools.maptools.org/).

the following command will do

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" E:\lakes.geojson e:\lakes.gml
```

Else if you have [QuantumGIS](http://www.qgis.org/), you can add your GML layer to map and by Right-Clicking the Layer, Select Save As to GeoJSON format.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried it & I got "ERROR 1: Unrecognized geometry type <Surface>." - does this mean that there a features in GML that cannot easily be converted to GeoJSON?

Comment: as per http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/11482/5850, you need GDAL 1.8.0 or above..what is your version?

Comment: @LarsGrammel try the latest version, http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/Download.aspx?file=release-1310-gdal-1-9-1-mapserver-6-0-3.zip

Comment: I used the latest fwTools for Windows (2.4.7). Will try the latest version of GDAL as you suggested.

Comment: GDAL 1.9.1 (included in the latest SDK) worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As vinayan said, ogr2ogr would be a good solution, but a handy way I've used in the past to quickly convert vector formats it to use this existing OpenLayers example:

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/vector-formats.html

Just draw your features or paste the data and hit add feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you have R Studio (it's a free software), you can use the converter located here to easily convert large GML files to GeoJSON:

https://gist.github.com/geotheory/7103991

Comment: That example has nothing to do with GML to GeoJSON

Answer (score 0):

You can use QGIS for it. Load the .gml file and export it in the format you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can if you want to look at gml data in a browser use https://gml.focus.no/. It is freeware.