# Convert GML to DXF using ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I cannot make ogr2ogr.exe work. I'm using GDAL 1.11.

I keep getting the following error message:

> ERROR 1: Did not get at least 2 values or invalid number of set of
>   coordinates 709993.98 6181946.65 32.36 709990.65
>   6181946.07
>   32.36 709992.47 6181935.8 32.36 709995.78 6181936.38 32.36 709993.98 6181946.65
>   32.36 ERROR 1: Invalid exterior ring

I run the following command:

> C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\ogr2ogr.exe -skipfailures -nlt
>   MULTILINESTRING25D -dim 3 -f "DXF" -a_srs "EPSG:25832" -spat 711000
>   6168300 713000 6168600 -geomfield posList bygning.DXF Bygning.gml

I'm working on a relatively big file 4.2GB.

**UPDATE: Example of data to import**

```
<gml:surfaceProperty>
    <gml:Surface srsName="EPSG:25832" srsDimension="3">
        <gml:patches>
            <gml:PolygonPatch>
                <gml:exterior>
                    <gml:LinearRing>
                        <gml:posList>
                            710820.22 6180637.52 36 710818.14 6180633.83 36 710825.47 6180629.71 36 710827.55 6180633.4 38.25 710828.6 6180637.3 38.25 710825.18 6180638.36 38.25 710824.22 6180635.27 36 710820.22 6180637.52 36
                        </gml:posList>
                    </gml:LinearRing>
                </gml:exterior>
            </gml:PolygonPatch>
        </gml:patches>
    </gml:Surface>
</gml:surfaceProperty>
```

Does the GML3 driver in org2ogr support surfaces?

**UPDATE 2 - making it simple**

I tried making a gml consisting of only one feature, same namespace etc. as before. I then output the feature to WKT.

Output WKT

"POLYGON ((711383.39 6182528.23,36.49 711379.31,6182528.35
36.48,711379.06 6182520.08,36.48 711383.15,6182519.97 36.48,711383.37 6182527.56,36.49 711383.39,6182528.23 36.49))"

Input GML
http://pastebin.com/76AGLWH0

Cleary the commas is placed in the wrong positions. The z-coordinate of the first point is parsed as the x-coordinate of the second feature. If I add -dim 3 or -nlt GEOMETRY, it adds zeroes.

BR
Thomas

Comment: Should be no problem according to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3942/how-to-convert-gml-surface-to-shp-using-ogr. It would help a lot if you could isolate one failing polygon, save it as complete GML file with all the xmlns stuff etc. and share it with us.

Comment: I'll try to see if I can get the data out of my 4.2GB file. I'm also having trouble locating some definition of GML3 and GML3 SF. I'm not sure PolygonPatches are supported by Ogr2ogr.

Comment: I found a definition here: http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=15201 and it seems PolygonPatches is part of GML3.1.1 SF

Comment: They are supported since version 1.8.0 http://upstream-tracker.org/changelogs/gdal/1.8.0/changelog.html The error speaks about number of coordinates. How about adding srsDimension="3" also after posList?

Comment: I found an example of 2D surface with polygon patch from ESRI China site http://bbs.esrichina-bj.cn/esri/viewthread.php?action=printable&tid=70881 and ogr2ogr reads the polygon from the 3 layer GML without problem.

Comment: Adding srsDimension="3" also into posList seems to correct your issue. `<gml:posList srsDimension="3">`. If you believe that it is not compulsory by the GML standard I suggest to make a GDAL bug report.

Comment: You mean adding it into my source GML - nothing to be done without changing the GML?

Comment: I fear that's the only solution for making your data to work correctly with GDAL. Fortunately you need only do one search-replace operation with a text editor.

Comment: Yes in a 4.2GB file - I'll have to parse it with Python lxml or something then. Could you write your comment as an answer?

Comment: I reported it as a bug - "Pages 58-59 of the GML 3.2.1 spec (OGC 07-036) note that it is expected that SRS attributes "will be specified at the direct position level only in rare cases". It seems to me that srsDimension goes hand-in-hand with srsName. Furthermore (p56): "The optional attribute srsDimension is the number of coordinate values in a position. This dimension is derived from the coordinate reference system. When the srsName attribute is omitted, this attribute shall be omitted." " http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Adding-srsDimension-at-the-posList-level-too-td5087644.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by GDAL which seems to require that 3-dimensional coordinates are specified in GML at position level as

```
<gml:posList srsDimension="3">
```

In the data dimensions are expressed only at geometry level

```
 <gml:Surface srsName="EPSG:25832" srsDimension="3">
```

This may be a bug or missing feature in GDAL and corresponding GDAL ticket http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5606 will show the resolution. First aid for making the data readable for GDAL is to add srsDimensions attribute to occasions of "posList" with a text editor.

```
<gml:posList>  =>  <gml:posList srsDimension="3">
```

Comment: I have tried it on a large scale - I did this on a 4.2GB file and it worked perfectly.